# ArcGIS Arcpy Scripting (arcpy.Near_analysis)

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I am working with an arcpy project and one component of it uses arcpy.near_analysis() tool. I am having a class which is taking CSV as input and creating feature class from it. Furthermore, I am having a function which takes in a pair of latitude longitude and create feature class. Than i tried to get the nearest feature by using these two feature classes. The script runs fine when I tried to run it outside the class, but when it runs inside the class it fill in (-1) which indicate no nearest feature and arcpy message said 0 nearest features. I have deleted almost all in memory variables, cursors, feature classes etc. but still getting same error. I am attaching below the samples of my code. Any help is appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNgTY.png)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it. Actually, I was deleting the cursor from memory after calling the arcpy.Near_analysis(), and for this reason it was creating the problem. However, whenever working with arcpy, **make sure to delete all in memory cursors(s) at the place where they used**. otherwise, they will interrupt the execution of the tools.
[image]